# How to include fontEncoding using docx4j library to support i18n

Tags: java, encoding, utf-16, docx4j

How to include font encoding using docx4j library to support i18n, I guess pdfSettings class might have helpers for this and I went through pdfSettings class with no luck, even gone through foSettings class but didnt find.

Can anyone please help me out with this.

Thanks

Comment: As it stands, this question doesn't make much sense.  docx files are usually encoded in UTF-8, and the font used to render a particular character is determined by docx4j's RunFontSelector and your font config (based on available physical fonts).   Feel free to rephrase your question to describe the actual issue you are having trouble with.

Comment: I am not able to convert local language docx file into pdf file with proper characters rendered. '#' is replaced with local language

Comment: Happy to look at this, but you'll need to post your docx somewhere

Comment: Sending content in docx for know, I think UTF-16 encoding is required.
పేరు replace_name
ಲಿಂಗ replace_gender
पत्ता replace_address
தொலைபேசி எண் replace_phno
ਈਮੇਲ ਆਈ.ਡੀ. replace_emailid

Comment: That's not enough. The docx says what fonts to use.

Comment: How to know which font to use to render local language.

Comment: See the RunFontSelector class.  Its complex, which is why I've offered to look at your issue if you can provide the docx.